# How to create thousand buttons quickly?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that can create 4000 new buttons but it took me 30 second to complete it. Is there anyway to make it faster?

```
For x = 1 To 4000

    Dim btnNew As New Button()

    btnNew.Width = 14
    btnNew.Height = 11

    btnNew.Location = New Point(a, b)
    Me.Controls.Add(btnNew)
    btn(k) = btnNew

Next
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do such a thing in the first place?  It might be quicker to add all the `Button` controls to a `Panel` or the like first and then add that to the form, but I don't know if it would make a difference.  You might also consider just drawing representations of buttons rather than creating actual controls, then handling the `MouseClick` event of the form to determine which "button" was clicked.

Comment: The biggest button count I've ever seen was on a periodic table (chemistry) program but even *that* had only a hundred or so (one per element). I'm interested in what application would need four *thousand* buttons :-)

Comment: Whatever problem you think you need 4000 buttons to solve - you don't.  There is indeed a faster way to solve your problem, but it means considering a vastly more sane design.  4000 buttons is *always* the wrong answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney maybe it is a new speed metric for computers  "How many buttons per second do you get on that thing?  Mine can only do 133/sec."

Comment: Wrap your code with `Me.SuspendLayout` and `Me.ResumeLayout`

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm looking forward to getting a terabutt computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three things that you really need to do:

1. Call SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout (to save all the multiple-layouts)
2. You could call AddRange instead.
3. If the container supports BeginUpdate/EndUpdate then use those two (to save re-painting).

So try:

```
Me.SuspendLayout()
Try
    For x As Integer = 1 To 4000

        Dim btnNew As New Button()

        btnNew.Width = 14
        btnNew.Height = 11

        btnNew.Location = New Point(a, b)
        Me.Controls.Add(btnNew)
        btn(k) = btnNew

    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
Finally
   Me.ResumeLayout()
End Try
```